# How do I import jquery file on Angular?

Tags: jquery, angular

I have a jquery file. I used `npm install jquery --save` and `npm install @types/jquery --save-dev`.Then I imported jquery file in .angular-cli.json . I getting `$ is not defined` and `jQuery is not defined` errors. It's not working.

Jquery file content:

```
var DatatablesSearchOptionsColumnSearch = function () {
    debugger;
    $.fn.dataTable.Api.register("column().title()", function () {
        return $(this.header()).text().trim()
    });
    return {
        init: function () {
            var t;
            t = $("#m_table_1").DataTable({
                responsive: !0,
                dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>\n\t\t\t<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7 dataTables_pager'lp>>",
                lengthMenu: [5, 10, 25, 50],
                pageLength: 10,
                language: {
                    lengthMenu: "Display _MENU_"
                },
                searchDelay: 500,
                ...
```

And I import in angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js",
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "assets/vendors/base/vendors.bundle.js",
       "assets/demo/default/base/scripts.bundle.js"
        ],
```

Comment: Please share your  code.

Comment: @wekabird have you try `declare const jQuery: any;
declare const $: any;`?

Comment: @Abhishek thanks for the answer.Only I will import jquery file. I won't use in .ts file.

Answer (score 0):

**Global Library Installation** as [Official documentation here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-lib#global-library-installation)

1. **Install from npm:**

   **`npm install jquery --save`**
2. **Add needed script files to scripts:**

   **`"scripts": [
     "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js"
   ],`**

Restart server if you're running it, and it should be working on your app.

---

If you want to use inside single component use **`import $ from 'jquery';`** inside your component

Comment: thanks for the answer. Only I will import jquery file. I won't use in .ts file. I am getting ´$ is not defined´ error at jquery file.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer:

> tag: selector js file that will run in .ts file
>
> src: js file path

```
loadScript(tag, src: string, loadOnce?: boolean) {
        debugger
        loadOnce = loadOnce || false;

        if (!this._scripts[src]) {
            this._scripts[src] = { src: src, loaded: false };
        }

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // resolve if already loaded
            if (this._scripts[src].loaded && loadOnce) {
                resolve({ src: src, loaded: true });
            } else {
                // load script tag
                let scriptTag = $('<script/>').
                    attr('type', 'text/javascript').
                    attr('src', this._scripts[src].src);

                $(tag).append(scriptTag);

                this._scripts[src] = { src: src, loaded: true };
                resolve({ src: src, loaded: true });
            }
        });
    }
```